# Bivariate random variable with R

Tags: r, correlation, matlab, t-distribution, copula

I am trying to transform this Matlab code into R. My goal is to generate a bivariate random variable with a pre-specified correlation. The code uses the idea of t-copula. I can't figure out how to write this in R. Will appreciate any help.

The code is:

```
n = 1000; 
rho = .7; 
nu = 1; 
T = mvtrnd([1 rho; rho 1], nu, n); 
U = tcdf(T,nu); 
X = [gaminv(U(:,1),2,1) tinv(U(:,2),5)];
```

Comment: Questions that rely on understanding a particular coding language and reading through code tend to be unsuccessful because (a) they limit your audience to a (very) small fraction and (b) any errors that might exist in the code will get translated into errors in the answers.  Therefore, please restate your question in terms of standard English and/or mathematical notation, telling us what the inputs will be, what the intended output is, and how it depends on the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

For a direct translation you need the obscure package [mvtnorm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/index.html) which provides `rmvnorm` (~ `mvtrnd`). For the rest of the functions, the mappings are built in, but they are
 more terse than Matlab:

```
tcdf(T, nu) ~ dt(T, nu)
gaminv(p, Alpha, Beta) ~ qgamma(p, Alpha, shape=Beta) #the keyword argument is important here
tinv(p, nu) ~ qt(p, nu)
```

And matrix concatenation is

```
cbind(left, right, ...)
rbind(top, bottom, ...)
```

Why are you using a mutivariate-T in one line (`mvtrnd`) and a univariate (`tcdf`) in another?

Comment: The problem is that rmvnorm requires a covariance matrix while my Matblab code simply takes a correlation coefficient. I am not sure how to cover this gap. The reason why I do all this, is to generate a bivariate random variable with correlation between the vectors, in order to simulate a model

Comment: `[1 rho; rho 1]` *is* a covariance matrix: it's a 2x2 positive definite symmetric matrix. You can create it in R with `matrix(c(1, rho, rho, 1), 2, 2)`. But it sounds like you might be better off starting playing with the [standard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution) (for normals, not ts, though they are close), which works because of [the linearity properties of Normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation).

Comment: I tried this code for a bivariate gamma with 0.8 correlation. THe matrix you see is the COV matrix, which is what the function requires. I wanted a gamma with E(X)=0.7 and V(X)=0.7: S = matrix(c(0.7,0.56,0.56,0.7),2,2);
n = 1000;
nu = 1;
T = rmvt(n, sigma = S, df = nu);
U = dt(T, nu);
X1 = qgamma(U[,1], scale = 1, shape=0.7);
X2 = qgamma(U[,2], scale = 1, shape=0.7);
X = cbind(X1,X2);

Comment: The code I wrote above doesn't work, it gives me a cor of 0.67 instead of 0.8

Comment: Does [this](http://dahtah.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/hello-world/) help?

Comment: Almost ! It made me change dt to pt, and now my gamma variables indeed looks like gamma. The correlation is now 0.77...however, Matlab gave 0.8 exactly, so I am still one step away from goal.

Comment: I changed the seed, ran it again and got 0.8 :-) Thanks for your help !!